# Temporarily set max col width and keep pandas styling - jupyter

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook, pandas-styles

I'm working in Jupyter Notebook and I've got a small df but one of the columns (series) has long strings in each row.

I'd like to temporarily extend the maximum column width for this df.

The problem I'm encountering is that when I use

```
with pd.option_context('display.max_colwidth', 200):
    print(df)
```

I lose the nice pandas df styling.

Is there a way I can get the usual nice output but with a larger column width temporarily? I know I can make a new object:

```
with pd.option_context('display.max_colwidth', 200):
    df_style = df.style
```

but this can't then be wrangled with as its a style object, not a df.

#### Reprex:

```
import pandas as pd

bard = pd.DataFrame(
    {'play': ['hamlet', 'macbeth', 'richard_iii'],
     'quote': ["To be, or not to be, that is the question.",
               "Is this a dagger which I see before me, This handle toward my hand?",
               "Now is the winter of our discontent  Made glorious summer by this sun of York."]}
)

with pd.option_context('display.max_colwidth', 200):
    print(bard)
```

Comment: I think you should use `display(bard)` instead of `print(bard)`.

Comment: perfect. Thanks, that's just what I was looking for